# How do you write a given stack of pitches?

Tags: sheet-music

[image]

Given the stack AFC, I was told that the first placement of notes is correct. I'm wondering why it is correct. I wrote the stack AFC as the second placement of notes and it is incorrect. Given the stack of pitches, how do you know when to move up the lines and when to move down the lines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your "stacks of pitches" are expected to be listed in top-to-bottom pitch order, so for AFC you'd expect the lowest note to be C.  Of course, even with that constraint there are a number of possibilities.  When starting with A4 (as you do here), I'd actually rather expect F4 and C4 next rather than the F3 and C3 the "correct" solution gives.

So there are probably some other rules in place for the non-standard terminology used here.  Basically all you can do is get a hold of the rules your teacher uses for these assignments and suck them up.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know where the question came from, but it's unusual to say 'a stack of...'.

I'd have put the notes in ascending order, but argue that they go in closed formation, as in the closest to each other that they can, so the top note A could easily go on the bass clef. It seems an odd way to test theory writing, although your answer is clearly not the best, as the notes aren't in the right order, whichever way they go.

I'd be questioning the question, and if possible, the questioner.

Comment: I'm guessing this is either for a non-music majors course or a very early level entry course.  Using non-standard terminology often allows people to more readily understand concepts, so that may be the teacher's approach.  I'd personally prefer to learn things within the standards to start instead of having to relearn concepts though.

Comment: @Basstickler - seems like an amateur attempt to me - and may be counter-productive!

Comment: Yeah, there's always a risk when you choose to educate someone using non-standard terminology.  It can be helpful in allowing someone to understand something but it could potentially leave them very confused when faced with the normal terminology.